# using pandas to extract a string from text file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
s = pd.read_csv("DIM.txt")
print(s)
```

This works good and I get output like below in different lines

```
abc,fgc,vvb....
sdc,trl,bgv...
```

And I like to show as below line by line

```
abc:fgc
sdc:trl
```

Comment: what you have in `DIM.txt` file ? show content of that file here

Comment: You just want to concatenate the first two columns?

Comment: file these values NAME,NickName,citynumber
abc,cvc,101 bvc,asd,203 dfc,rte,304

Comment: just want to strip everything and show just first two string line by line

Answer (score 0):

As I see, your input file has no "title" (column names) row.
So in this case you should pass *header=None* parameter.

Another detail is that *s* (variable name) can be associated with a *Series*. As the result of *read_csv* is a **DataFrame**, use rather *df* variable name.

To sum up, the code to read your file should be:

```
df = pd.read_csv("DIM.txt", header=None)
```

The result (for your input sample) is:

```
     0    1        2
0  abc  fgc  vvb....
1  sdc  trl   bgv...
```

(if your sample contains more commas, there will be more columns).

To generate your desired result (concatenation of column *0* and *1*),
run:

```
result = df[0] + ':' + df[1]
```

The result is:

```
0    abc:fgc
1    sdc:trl
dtype: object
```

Comment: since i have it one string value i get only one colum as 0 not 0,1,2

Comment: You didn't provide the content of your input file, so I assumed that *abc,fgc,vvb....* is the first line in this file and *sdc,trl,bgv...* is the second line. I used just this file as input and got the presented result.

Comment: how can i use a split in this case ?

Comment: *split* is used to convert a string into a list of fragments, cutting it on each occurrence of a substring or single char. But here we have to **concatenate** two columns, putting a ":" between them.

Comment: since this one large string, i can just split it  untill second "," so i am okay to show abc,dev ...red,tyz so on